# Executable runs differently when started by non-graphical means

Tags: script, window, windows-server

I'm at a dead end and any input would be greatly appreciated. I'm working with a third party application for which I do not have access to the code. It routinely stops working and needs to be restarted, but I'm stuck using it. To automate this restart, based on its connections to a database, I have tried many things. The two that seemingly worked were using software to run it as a service and restart the service from command line, and I also set up a system which uses a scheduled task and restarts the executable. However, any time the executable is started in any way that is not done through windows explorer causes it to have the same new error. From what I understand there should not be a difference in how the executable is started, but there clearly is. Any input/ideas would useful, thanks. It is running on a Windows Server 2008 R2. The error is not a windows error but on the side of the database. The error never happens when the executable is started graphically and it always happens when the executable is started by script. The error however does not say anything other than 'Error while processing in thread blahblah at line blahblah', I however do not have access to see that line of code. When I set it as a service or run it through task scheduler, I set it to run under the same account that I use to run it graphically.

Comment: And what error? Presumably the methods you are using are not running with under the proper account

Comment: Could you include the exact error message please? Are you allowed to tell us which program it is? That would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

How do you start your program from script (code) ? perhaps your executable needs admin privileges  or parameters ?